How to convert python integers to a pairing element in group in Charm-Crypto?
In the documentation of the charm-crypto library, in the implemented  schemes there is often a paragraph like this: `
groupObj = PairingGroup('SS512')
k = groupObj.random(GT)

where k is the <pairing.Element> data to be encrypted.  How can I convert an integer to an element similar to k so that after decoding I can convert it back to an integer.  Can the method X=1000m+i,1<=i<=999 such that exist (X,y) belongs to the ECC curve and calculate m = P.X//1000 be implemented here?  Can anyone help me do this?
pairing.Element corresponds to an integer in charm-crypto

this question is not coherent in its current format. perhaps change it to somthing more readable.

how to ask a good question:
how to ask
